# Problem with saving and reopening a vscode workspace initiated from WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code

I open my vscode with `code .` command from WSL terminal because I want to work directly in my WSL. It works fine and for example, the file explorer of vscode shows directory structures based on WSL machine and not based on my Windows machine.

My problem is however that, when I save a workspace using `File -> Save Workspace As`, **it saves it again as a workspace in my Windows machine**. So when I close and open my vscode again and use `Open Workspace...` to open the already saved workspace(in previous step), explorer reads directories from Windows machine.

You might ask what's the difference between saving files in `/mnt/c/Users/[user]/Desktop` or `C:\Users\[user]\Desktop`, but the problem is two things:

1. I might open a session from a directory in WSL that is (unlike Desktop) inaccessible from Windows.
2. Even if my Desktop is my current working directory, I may add another directory to my workspace (using `Add Folder to Workspace...`) and even if it is a path accessible from Windows, the next time I open the workspace, I will get an exclamation mark and such an error near that directory in explorer:

> C:\mnt\d\Files_And_Downloads\Google Drive_Code . Can not resolve workspace folder

I suspect this is a bug, vscode has mixed the WSL path and Windows path. So anyone who uses [Remote - WSL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) and can tell me what's going on here?

Comment: To anyone who might bump into the same problem, I'm not posting this as an answer because it's too dumb. When you install Remote WSL extension, they automatically add an icon to the sidebar of your vscode, so when you save a workspace you DON'T have to reopen it the same way you open other workspaces, you should open it from that section in the sidebar and then you'll be able to continue using your remote workspace without any problems. HTH.